# Multiple markers in Polyline point in Google Map using Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers, polyline

We are developing a taxi-hailing app where drivers can have multiple drop-off locations and we are using Flutter for the app.

Is it possible to display multiple markers within the polyline route in Google Maps using flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

you can take any point(latlang) from the polyline(contains a list of latlang points) and add a marker on the
same point

```
final Set<Marker> _markers = {};
final Set<Polyline>_polyline={};
```